# Luke 16:8, what is the accurate translation "age" or "world"?

Tags: word-study, luke

Luke 16:8 (ASV):

> 8. {cf6 And his lord commended the unrighteous steward because he had done wisely: for **the sons of this world** are for their own generation wiser than the sons of the light.}

Luke 16:8 (DRB):

> And the lord commended the unjust steward, forasmuch as he had done wisely: for **the children of this world** are wiser in their generation than the children of light.

Luke 16:8 (LV):

> 8. et laudavit dominus vilicum iniquitatis quia prudenter fecisset quia filii huius **saeculi** prudentiores filiis lucis in generatione sua sunt

The phrase: "sons of this world" has the following variations:

- sons, children and people.
- world and age.

What is the most accurate translation?

For example:

- Sons of this world.
- Sons of this age.
- children of this world.
- children of this age.
- people of this world.
- people of this age.

Thus, what is the most accurate translation according to the original Greek manuscripts?

Comment: There won't be a single translation. 'World' is usually from the Greek word _kosmos_ and  'age' is from the Greek word _aion_. One draws attention to the _place of habitation (among humanity in civilisation)_ and the other draws attention to the _mortal and timely aspect of the humanity_.

Comment: @NigelJ what about the original Greek manuscripts, they stated "kosmos" or "aion"?

Comment: Well you are asking someone to undertake a study of all the texts involved. Quite a lot of work :) I have just come off a 12 hour night shift (Security). And I really don't feel like doing it right now :)

Comment: @NigelJ you can answer later.

Comment: My profile has my website. My website has my email address. Now I am off to bed. God be with you, @salah.

Answer (score 1):

The operative word in Luke 16:8 which is translated either "world" or "age" is αἰῶνος (aiōnos) from the root αἰών (aión).  The primary meaning of this word is "age" or "aeon", a period of time.  The NAS concordance gives the following meaning:

> Word Origin: from a prim. root appar. mean. continued duration
>   Definition: a space of time, an age

BDAG gives four basic meanings for this word, the second of which is the one allocated to Luke 16:8, namely, "**a segment of time as a particular unit of history, *age***", eg, 1 Cor 3:18, Matt 12:32, Mark 4:19, Luke 16:8, etc.

The phase (literally) "sons of this age", is common Hebrew idiom for "people of the present time" or equivalent.  See also Luke 20:34.

In a very few places it is also capable (according to BDAG) of meaning, "**the world as a special concept, *the world***", eg, Heb 1:2.